# java.lang.NumberFormatException: null for update servlet

Tags: java, jsp

JSP

```
<%@page import ="update.*,tables.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*,id.*"%>
<%getter ab=ID.getID(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")));%>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<body>
<form method="post" action="Update" onsubmit="location.reload()"> 
<div class="form-row">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=ab.getId()%>"/>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
            <label for="inputuName4">User Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputuName4" placeholder="Username"  name="username" value=<%=ab.getUsername()%> required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputlName4">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputlName4" placeholder="Last Name"   name="lastname" value=<%=ab.getLastname()%> required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputmName4">Middle Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputmName4" placeholder="Middle Name"  name="middlename" value=<%=ab.getMiddlename()%> required>
         </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputfName4">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputfName4" placeholder="First Name"  name="firstname" value=<%=ab.getFirstname()%> required>
          </div>
```

SERVLET

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Connection con=connector.getConnection();
        String id=request.getParameter("id"); 
        getter ab = ID.getID(Integer.parseInt(id));
        String username = request.getParameter("username");             
        try {
            String sql="Update data set username=?,lastname=?,middlename=?,firstname=?,email=?,password=?,province=?,caddress=?,city=?,zip=? where id="+ab.getId();
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, username);
```

i'm really confused on why my getter ab = ID.getID(Integer.parseInt(id));
is the only error please help

> im confused on whether or not the data type used in line 2 of my jsp is 
>   wrong since that line is just my error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
org.apache.jsp.indexUpdate_jsp._jspService(indexUpdate_jsp.java:128)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Comment: What is the value of the 'id' parameter in the request?

Comment: In JSP everything in a [scriptlet](https://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-scriptlet-tag#scriptlet) (between `<%` and `%>`) must be a valid Java expression. What is the type of the `ab` variable? Is `getter` the intended class? Can you please post the error message you are getting?

Comment: It looks like that `request.getParameter("id")` is returning null and because of that it's throwing `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Any recommendation since im using mysql db,servlet and jsp

Comment: the value of id is the primary key of my table in mysql